# Convert htaccess RewriteRule to Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have tried a couple of conversion tools to convert my htaccess file to nginx format.  The rule I am trying to get to work is:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Worksheets
RewriteRule worksheetsAwaitingApproval$ worksheetsAwaitingApproval.php [L]
```

The above htaccess file is located in a subfolder called `superusers`

Once converted to nginx, it looks like this:

```
location /superusers/ {
    rewrite /worksheetsAwaitingApproval$ /worksheetsAwaitingApproval.php break;
}
```

However, when I navigate to the page on my nginx server, i get the folowing error message:

> No input file specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `worksheetsAwaitingApproval.php` is local to the `/superusers/` subfolder. Your rewrite rule must either extract the subfolder or you must specify it explicitly. Try either:

```
rewrite worksheetsAwaitingApproval$ /superusers/worksheetsAwaitingApproval.php
```

or:

```
rewrite ^(.*)/worksheetsAwaitingApproval$ $1/worksheetsAwaitingApproval.php
```